# Delete commented TimeStamp(#Wed Sep 07 10:47:35 CEST 2016) in .properties files in java

Tags: java

I have a folder which contains many .properties files and each files has TimeStamp which is commented(#Wed Sep 07 10:47:35 CEST 2016). I need to remove this commented timestamp(#Wed Sep 07 10:47:35 CEST 2016) present in each .properties files using java. as i am new to .properties not sure how to delete the comment present in .properties file. 
Please Help me out.

```
Properties prop=new Properties(); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\PracticeElement__i22_messages.properti‌​es");
ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
prop.store(arrayOut, null); 
String string = new String(arrayOut.toByteArray(), "8859_1");
String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
String content = string.substring(string.indexOf(sep) + sep.length());
out.write(content.getBytes("8859_1"));
```

Comment: Either treat it as a text file and remove the line manually or use the ``Properties`` class to ``load`` the file, then ``store`` it. Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: Can we ask *why* you want to delete the comment? It shouldn't affect the result of loading the file in as a `Properties` object... and I'd strongly discourage using .properties files for any other purpose.

Comment: When i update the properties file, everytime timestamp is updated and i dont want this timestamp to get updated. so i am deleting the comment line alone.

Comment: Properties prop=new Properties();
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\PracticeElement__i22_messages.properties");
  ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  prop.store(arrayOut, null);
  String string = new String(arrayOut.toByteArray(), "8859_1");
  String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
  String content = string.substring(string.indexOf(sep) + sep.length());
  out.write(content.getBytes("8859_1"));

Comment: But whole file is deleted. Not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Please edit the code into your question, rather than leaving it as comments. I'd also urge you to use a `StringWriter` to write the properties to, in order to avoid unnecessary conversions.

Comment: Hey whether this code delete all the comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you need to load the property file before before storing arrayOut.
Please try this code,

```
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\PracticeElement__i22_messages.properti‌​es");
        Properties prop=new Properties(); 
        prop.load(in);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\PracticeElement__i22_messages.properti‌​es"); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
        prop.store(arrayOut, null); 
        String string = new String(arrayOut.toByteArray(), "8859_1"); 
        String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
        String content = string.substring(string.indexOf(sep) + sep.length()); 
        out.write(content.getBytes("8859_1"));
        in.close();
        out.close();
```

Note : This will delete entire comments in the property file.